# Assign value to textbox dynamically in button click event in php

Tags: php

This is my Html Code :

```
<input type="text" id="state" name="state"  autocomplete="off">
<input type="text" id="district" name="district" autocomplete="off">
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

and this is my php code in server side :

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){        
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    //what we have to write here to assign this value to 2nd textbox.   
}
```

Please help me to solve this.....

Comment: can you explain yourself in details

Comment: Why would you event go to the server side to do that?

Comment: that is my requirement......but i know how to assign by using javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you're involving PHP, then it's not going to be as smooth as JavaScript (you'll see the screen refresh).

In this case as well you will need to have the form and the PHP on the same page:

```
<?php

$district = "";
$state    = "";

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){        
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    $district = $state;
}

?>

<form method="post" action="">

<input type="text" id="state" name="state" value="<?php echo $state; ?>" autocomplete="off">
<input type="text" id="district" name="district" value="<?php echo $district; ?>" autocomplete="off">
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

So once you type something into the first text field, and submit, you'll see that it appears in the second text field.

Comment: i was tried like that but it is not working....

Comment: I forgot the form, can you try again?

Comment: ya already added but not working...

Comment: Remember to refresh your cache (or delete it). It works fine for me. I load the page, type something in the first textbox, and click the submit button. Then I see the same thing in the second textbox.

Comment: finally got it bhayya...did a small mistake in my page...